# image src replace with an array

Tags: image, extern

how to find the image tags in the string and find the src of the image tag and replace with an array which contains new src.

```
array(
    [0] => YogurtParfait.png
    [1] => Smoothie_0.png
    [2] => Waffle.png
    [3] => EggSandwich_0.png
    [4] => BlueberryMuffins.png
)
```

this is the array I want replace with string src.

```
$string = 'This is my test <img src="link_to_image1">, some other text
<img src="link_to_image1"> 
<img src="link_to_imag"> 
<img src="link_to_im"> 
<img src="link_to_imag">.
```

I want get the out put like this

```
$string = 'This is my test 
<img src="YogurtParfait.png">,   
some other text<img src="Smoothie_0.png">
<img src="Waffle.png"> 
<img src="EggSandwich_0.png">
<img src="BlueberryMuffins.png">.
```

Comment: Does all `img` tag has the same `src` as `link_to_image1`?

Comment: no all are different ,and dynamic

Answer (score 0):

In case all the `<img>` tags really have the same `src` attributes, you can do it iteratively:

```
$links = array("YogurtParfait.png", ...);
$string = "This is my ...";
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $string = str_replace("link_to_image1", $link, $string);
}
```

In case they are in fact `link_to_image1`, `link_to_image2` ... then:

```
$links = array("YogurtParfait.png", ...);
$string = "This is my ...";
foreach ($links as $k => $link) {
    $string = str_replace("link_to_image$k", $link, $string);
}
```

**Update**

As it turned out the `src` is dynamic so:

```
$links = array("YogurtParfait.png", ...);
$string = "This is my ...";

$startpos = strpos($string, '<img'); // position of first occurrence of <img
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $string =
        substr($string, 0, $startpos) // the part before the <img part
        . preg_replace(
             '/(<img src=")[^"]+(">)/',
             '\1' . $link . '\2',

             // the part from the actual <img part
             substr($string, $startpos) 
        );
    // get position of next <img part
    $startpos = strpos($string, '<img', $startpos + 1); 
}
```

Comment: the array like array(
[0]=>http://exdomadin/Funk/files/YogurtParfait.png
[1]=>http://exdomadin/Funk/files/Smoothie_0.png
[2]=>http://exdomadin/Funk/files/Waffle.png
[3]=>http://exdomadin/Funk/files/EggSandwich_0.png
[4]=>http://exdomadin/Funk/files/BlueberryMuffins.png
)

Comment: image src also different in the string $string = 'This is my test <img src="link_to_image1">, some other text
<img src="link_t"> 
<img src="link_to_ima"> 
<img src="link_to_imag"> 
<img src="link_to_image">.

Comment: how to replace the first src to array[0], second src to array[1] finally print the sting

Comment: I've fixed the replacement. At the end `$string` should contain the updated string

Comment: i cant understand fejese,pls explain me '\1' . $link . '\2',

Comment: There are 2 capturing groups in the regex pattern, these can be referenced by `\1` and `\2`. So effectively you replace `<img src="...">` with `<img src="$newlink">` where `...` is restricted to not be a `"` by `[^"]`. See here for more explanation: http://regex101.com/r/cL7nV0/1

Comment: Sorry just realised that this is not doing the job right. I'll update it in a bit

Comment: Updated to fix an issue of replacing all occurrence of href with the last link every time.

Comment: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given   strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string  i am getting this error :(

Answer (score 0):

Let `$array1` be the name of the variable containing your array. Then:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $i=>$src) 
    $array['link_to_image' . ($i + 1)] = $src;

$output = strtr($string, $array2);
```

Comment: Mr.Radu image src and array ,both have the values dynamically.

Comment: define **dynamically** for **image src**: what change and what does not change? The **src** attribute will be always of form **link_to_image<number>**?

Comment: maybe `preg_replace`?